# Does False logically entails everything

Tags: logic

Suppose I have this entailment

$ False \models (A \wedge B) $
Is this entailment true ?

Is all entailment that has $False$ on the left hand side true no matter the right hand side ?

Comment: This is the [principle of explosion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_explosion).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To grasp the intuition behind this so-called *Principle of Explosion*,
it may be instructive to use truth tables.

$(A\land \neg A)\to B~$ is a tautology.

[image]

Note that the conjunction $A\land \neg A~$ is always false. It is a contradiction or *falsehood*.

Note, too, that the implication $(A\land \neg A)\to B~$ is always true regardless of the truth value of $B$, but we cannot infer from it that $B$ is true.

[image]

Likewise, we cannot infer that $B$ is false.

[image]

Comment: I find this explanation circular, as it assumes we know how to correctly evaluate the truth table of $\to$. In particular, it assume $\text{F} \to \text{F} = T$. But this truth-table rule for $\to$, along with the standard interpretation that $\to$ means "implies," is basically motivated by the explosion / *ex falso quodlibet* principle, no?

Comment: @WillG The truth table for logical implication is often given as a "definition" in introductory texts. It can, however, be justified from what might be called "first principles." See, for example, https://dcproof.wordpress.com/2017/12/28/if-pigs-could-fly/

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: yes. If we define $A \vDash C$ to hold if and only if there is no valuation which makes $A$ true and $C$ false, then in particular $A \vDash C$ will hold in the case where there is just no valuation at all which makes $A$ true. So, if $\bot$ (or *False*) is defined to be such that there is no valuation which makes $\bot$ true, we will have $\bot \vDash C$ for any $C$. Voilà.

But ...

What if we meant to use $\vDash$ to express entailment in an intuitive sense? Then all bets are off! Because it is far from obvious that the intuitive notion of $A$'s entailing $C$ is captured by something of the kind "there is no valuation which makes $A$ true and $C$ false". For that definition of course doesn't impose any requirement for some sort of relevant connection between $A$ and $C$! And you might well think that for $A$ to genuinely entail $C$, there should be some connection between the premise and conclusion.

Logicians have been arguing about this for 2500 years more or less. Aristotle wrote

> A deduction is speech (logos) in which, certain things having been supposed, something different from those supposed results of necessity because of their being so.

Note the "because of their being so". This is naturally read as requiring that a connection of relevance between $A$ and $C$ if indeed $C$ is to be a genuine deduction from $A$.

OK: we're not going to settle that debate here! But, in summary, it is trivial that $\bot \vDash C$ for any $C$ if we buy into the sort of definition of $\vDash$ I sketched. However it is a non-trivial question whether that definition is the best regimentation or sharpening-up of our pre-formal notion of entailment. And there are alternative relevance-respecting formal logics which handle $\vDash$ differently and for which the explosive inference $\bot \therefore C$ doesn't count as valid.

Answer (score 0):

In classical logic and similar formal systems of reasoning, yes, a logical falsehood entails anything. This is known as the *[principle of explosion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_explosion)*, also referred to as *ex falso quodlibet* meaning "from falsehood, anything" in Latin.

For instance, here is a brief proof of $\bot \vdash P$ in propositional logic where $P$ is any complex formula:

$\{ 1 \} \:\:\: 1. \bot \:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:$ premise

$\{ 1 \} \:\:\: 2. \bot \vee P \:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\: 1 \:\:\: \vee$I

$\{ 1 \} \:\:\: 3. P \:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\: 2 \:\:\:$ identity law

However, to be more precise, you state $\bot \vDash P$ which asserts semantic validity. You could show this nonetheless by constructing a truth table and observing there is no interpretation in which the premise $\bot$ is true and the conclusion $P$ is false. Of course, this is because $\bot$ is always false by definition.